# Firestore doing last update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firestore in a VOIP app and here's my scenario:

- User A calls users B, a new firestore document is created
- There is a listener on user B device that listens for new document having B as
  receiver
- After document is created with status = calling
- User B receives the new document snapshot
- User A quickly marks status = end after the document is created
- User B sets status = ringing

So here the issue:

Last firestore update which I see in Firebase console is ringing, it should be end but since status = ringing was set after user A ended his call, that becomes last status. There is no way to see if last end is set so B user doesnt set his ringing status.

How do I resolve to that "end" is the last status. Is there an option for final update?

EDIT: Can this be done by creating rules that if once a status = end, it can not be changed?

I have created the following rule but it doesn't work:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 10, 28);
      allow update: if resource.data.status != 'end'; // I have added this line only
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. What did you expect the rules to do? What did they do instead? We'll also need to see the minimal code with which to reproduce the problem as security rules on their own do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore Rules was the solution to fix this issue. Basically I had the default rule which has allow write in it, and **write = create, update, delete** so I had to change write with create, delete, read in order to make it work.

After updating my rules to this, it works now:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, create, delete: if request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 10, 28);
      allow update: if resource.data.status != 'end';
    }
  }
}
```